# Redirect commons-logging output in Maven3 Mojo

Tags: java, logging, maven-2, maven-3, apache-commons-logging

For the [Flyway](http://code.google.com/p/flyway) Maven plugin, I need to call a number of libraries that log using **commons-logging** (Flyway, Spring, ...)

In Maven2, I could use [**maven-plugin-log4j**](http://pyx4j.com/snapshot/pyx4j/pyx4j-maven-plugins/maven-plugin-log4j/index.html) to accomplish this. This is what the output looks like:

```
[INFO] [flyway:history {execution: default-cli}]
[INFO] Hsql does not support locking. No concurrent migration supported.
```

In Maven3 however, this doesn't work so well:

```
[INFO] --- flyway-maven-plugin:1.3.2-SNAPSHOT:history (default-cli) @ flyway-sample ---
15.04.2011 09:49:10 com.googlecode.flyway.core.dbsupport.hsql.HsqlDbSupport <init>
INFO: Hsql does not support locking. No concurrent migration supported.
```

**How can I get clean logging output in Maven3?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found out what the issue was.

In order to support Maven 2, the plugin depends on **maven-core** version **2.2.1**.

This version of maven-core pulls in an **slf4j-jdk14** dependency.

This doesn't do anything under Maven 2, but in Maven 3 it gets used and **redirects all logging output to JDK 1.4 logging** (which is an absolute pain to configure).

In order to get the commons-logging output redirected to the Maven log **in both Maven 2 and Maven 3**, I now have the following setup working:

```
<!-- Stop redirecting to JDK 1.4 logging -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.1</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-jdk14</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>

<!-- Log4J to Maven Log -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.pyx4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-plugin-log4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.1</version>
</dependency>

<!-- Slf4j to Log4J -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.6</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use [AbstractMojo.getLog()](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.0.3/maven-plugin-api/apidocs/org/apache/maven/plugin/AbstractMojo.html#getLog%28%29) to use the Maven provided Logger.

Comment: This doesn't really help me, as the vast majority of the code that logs is NOT maven-specific (Think flyway-core, spring, ...).

Comment: AbstractMojo uses a [SystemStreamLog](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/maven/maven-3/tags/maven-3.0.3/maven-plugin-api/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/plugin/logging/SystemStreamLog.java?view=markup) which in turn just does System.out.println("[" + prefix + "] " + sWriter.toString()); - so you might just configure their loggers to do the same. Maybe maven2.x provided such a configuration?

Comment: There is a MavenLoggerManager and a PrintStreamLogger in [maven-embedder/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/cli/](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/maven/maven-3/tags/maven-3.0.3/maven-embedder/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/cli/) which might help.. but it doesn't look that great :/